# How to extract all the youtube video links for a particular youtube channel using Youtube-dl?

Tags: bash, shell-script, youtube-dl

How to extract all the youtube video links URL for a particular youtube channel using Youtube-dl ubuntu shell script? the file should contain certain information like: 
Video URL
Video Title
Video Description
Video like and dislike count
Video tags 
Is it possible to get all the information for a particular channel URL in a single text file? I've used the script to get Title, video duration and description. How can I add all the things written above.

```
$ youtube-dl --get-title --get-duration --get-description -a links.txt --skip-download >saved.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Updated the things.

Comment: Short answer: you can't

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about youtube-dl but there is a one fork **yt-dlp**.

```
$ yt-dlp -j --flat-playlist <youtube-channel-link> | jq -r '.id' | sed 's_^_https://youtu.be/_' > links.txt
```

Above command worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You'd need an additional wrapper for youtube-dl that parses all playlists or individual videos from the channel because youtube-dl itself does not contain this ability.

The closest youtube-dl does by itself is parse a playlist for downloading all of its individual videos.

Comment: I need video details only.

Comment: So? It doesn't matter. youtube-dl doesn't have this function itself. You'd need some other utility, one that can get all of the content in a Youtube channel. You've asked us specifically to help you get this working using youtube-dl and the answer is that you cannot.